# How do I deploy .NET 6 web app to IIS 10?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, deployment, .net-6.0, iis-10

I've read the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 and still cannot get it working.

To be clear, I'm trying to run the ASPNET MVC app as in-process (as opposed to reverse proxy to the app's Kestrel webserver) on IIS 10 and have installed the ASP.NET Core Module/Hosting Bundle for .NET 6, I've setup a separate AppPool and set it to non-managed code for my ASPNET app.

The various articles I've read seem to be very much out of date, so I guess some information applicable to .NET 6 would be very useful.
Does anyone know the definitive steps to deploying and configuring a .NET 6 ASPNET MVC app to IIS?

I've tried the steps outlined in various articles, including https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Run a report to rule out the common issues please, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Nobody is supposed to give you step-by-step guides, as your web app can be special and crash on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio:

1. Publish your project to folder with this settings [image: publish settings]
   IIS:
2. Create pool with non-managed code setting and identity for running the app.
3. Create site with our pool, path to published project and the specified IP:Port.
4. Configure the environment variables if necessary (select site -> Editor configuration -> select syste.webServer/aspNetCore -> click ... near the environmentVariables | Count -> Add variables and apply it).
5. Set hostingModel to inprocess.
6. Set stdLogEnabled and path if necessary.
7. Run and check your site. Everything should work fine.

Comment: While you are trying hard to help, 1) the steps you listed are far from complete (ASP.NET Core module is not even mentioned), 2) you mixed publishing steps (from VS) with deployment steps (IIS side changes). Stack Overflow isn't the right place to write tutorials on "how-to", or there will be countless long answers that rarely are useful. Instead, people should be redirected to search engines for tutorials and come back only with specific questions.

Comment: Thanks @Weldis, it was the portable executable setting that did the trick, it's running fine now, though I will neeef to sirt out the service account for the app pool.

Comment: @LexLi 1)I skipped this because the author said he installed the ASP.NET Hosting bundle. 2)I included the step with VS because it was an important part of publishing in this case.

Comment: @endurium You can use any windows identity, but remember to give the right permissions for this identity, if you use SQL Server with Integrated Security option. And permissions for read/write from disk if it needed.